# Formatting data CIColorCube

Tags: ios, nsdata, exc-bad-access, core-image, cifilter

I am trying to use CIColorCube CIFilter of CoreImage framework, i tried arbitrary 3D Luts to images , i wrapped the 3D luts to NSData before passed as an argument to the CIColorCube CIFilter. but i am getting EXC_BAD_ACCESS exception..
Here is my code :

CIContext *context = [CIContext contextWithOptions:nil];
    CIFilter *filter = [CIFilter filterWithName:@"CIColorCube"];

```
uint8_t color_cube_data[4096*4] = {
    153, 255, 255, 1,
    170, 255, 255, 1,
    186, 255, 255, 1,
    204, 255, 255, 1,
    221, 255, 255, 1,
    237, 255, 255, 1,
    255, 255, 255, 1};
NSData * cube_data =[NSData dataWithBytes:color_cube_data length:4096*sizeof(float)*4];

[filter setValue:originalImage forKey:kCIInputImageKey];
[filter setValue:[NSNumber numberWithFloat:16] forKey:@"inputCubeDimension"];
[filter setValue:cube_data forKey:@"inputCubeData"];
CIImage *result = [filter valueForKey:kCIOutputImageKey];
CGImageRef cgImage =[context createCGImage:result fromRect:originalImage.extent];
imgVw_Result.image=[UIImage imageWithCGImage:cgImage];
```

Did i missed something please help 
Thanks

Comment: [_colorCube setValue:color_cube_data forKey:@"inputCubeData"];

Comment: I think you are talking about [filter setValue:cube_data forKey:@"inputCubeData"]; line , i think this is not a problem

Answer (score 1):

`CIColorCube` requires rgb data of type float in the range `0.0 to 1.0`, whereas your `color_cube_data` structure is of type `uint8_t`. Further, in your `cube_data` constructor, you've actually accounted for a type float ("`sizeof(float)`") which means you're not supplying the correct byte size to your filter's NSData structure.

See listing 5-3 in the following documentation:
https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/GraphicsImaging/Conceptual/CoreImaging/ci_filer_recipes/ci_filter_recipes.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP30001185-CH4-SW1